# 3rd party API like IBPy for Interactive Brokers python API?

Tags: programming, python, algorithmic-trading, interactive-brokers

I've read some tutorial of the Interactive Brokers API's TWS and it seems very low level and requires so much work just to place a simple market order.

I've come across IBPy and just wondering how reliable is it? It's very simple to use, but should anything go wrong, is it quite easy to debug?

I've also heard that IBPy is no longer being developed, so it won't support Python 3.0 and up. In that case, is there something similar to IBPy that's just as easy to use and is updated quite frequently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with using IbPy is not only that it does not support Python 3 but even more importantly it's anchored to an older version of IB's API so it's missing a lot of features IB has added in recent years.

If you like the feel of IbPy, [ibpythonic](https://github.com/quantrocket-llc/ibpythonic) is near drop-in replacement for IbPy that works with Python 3 and the newer versions of IB's API. It's maintained by (and used by) [QuantRocket](http://www.quantrocket.com). (Disclaimer: I am affiliated with QuantRocket.)

Another option to look at is [ib_insync](https://github.com/erdewit/ib_insync). It replaces IB's asynchronous programming model with a more synchronous programming model and has an active [user group](https://groups.io/g/insync).

Comment: Brian, thanks for all your contributions, any plans to update ibpythonic to support API 9.74?

Comment: I second the comment from misantroop. Redundant as this may be, a head's up would be helpful before porting over to the native API/another 3rd party, as the IbPy-like interface has always served me well.

Comment: @Brian from QuantRocket. I just looked at the QuantRocket website and it was interesting.  Is QuantRocket at all close to supporting intraday trading  that can go on all day  ? I have a strategy that uses the Bovespa Exchange stocks and I'm trying to figure out if there's any platform that allows such a thing ? Thanks.

Comment: @misantroop if ibpythonic doesn't work with 9.74, please open a GitHub issue.

Comment: @Brian from QuantRocket, I would but there doesn't seem to be a possibility to do so (issues tab missing).

Comment: @misantroop sorry try now